# Where does the language Databasic originate?

Tags: programming-languages

Does anyone know where Databasic originates from, and any resources that could help me learn this language?

I'm assuming it's Basic but looking at some sample code there are database-specific features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend looking at the official documentation: http://download.northgate-is.com/reality/V14%20Manuals/help.htm

The company's web page also might have some useful information: http://www.northgate-reality.com/products.php

Answer (score 0):

There is also DataBASIC that was developed by Metso Automation.  It is a Basic variant that includes Database access commands, and has been used in Metso and Telvent products.  I've been unable to find any Web resources on it, and depend on the documentation that comes with my Telvent product.